# how to use Oracle Precompiler on mac

Tags: c, oracle, macos, proc, precompiler

I have get stuck here few days，anyone who can help is grateful.
The main question is about using oracle Precompiler on mac.

I have tried step by step like this:
1.As Oracle official documents,I download three files:

```
1.instantclient-basic-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0.zip
2.instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0-2.zip
3.instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-18.1.0.0.0.zip
```

2.then follow steps as mentioned here https://github.com/InstantClientTap/homebrew-instantclient:

```
brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
brew install instantclient-basic
brew install instantclient-sdk
brew install instantclient-sqlplus
```

I used sqlplus connect to my Oracle server which run in docker successfully.

3.BUT, due to this tool not provide install precompiler.
So I download
instantclient-precomp-macos.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip
then unzip it.

4.I got a folder name precomp which have a folder name admin ,and in the admin I have two files pcbcfg.cfg and pcscfg.cfg, I put the precomp folder into /usr/local/lib/ which mentioned when I use `proc` commond in my Terminal like this :

`System default option values taken from:/usr/local/lib/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg.`

5.also, I got a folder name sdk, bcuz I have install sdk by homebrew, so I copy the exec files name proc and procob in the sdk to `/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sdk/18.1.0.0.0-2/lib/sdk/`

6.and then I put all the .h files in the include folder to `/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sdk/18.1.0.0.0-2/lib/sdk/include`
just in case, I also copy them into `usr/local/include`.

7.And I changed the lines in the pcscfg.cfg like this:
`sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include,/usr/include,/usr/local/include/,/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sdk/18.1.0.0.0-2/include,/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sdk/18.1.0.0.0-2/lib/sdk/include,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include)`

that's all I have done.

So I just write a test.pc:

```
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA; 
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

varchar username[20],passwd[20],dbn[20];

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

strcpy(username.arr, "c##yuyu");
username.len = strlen("c##yuyu");
strcpy(passwd.arr,"123456");
passwd.len = strlen("123456");
strcpy(dbn.arr, "ORCLCDB.localdomain");
dbn.len = strlen("ORCLCDB.localdomain");

EXEC SQL CONNECT: username IDENTIFIED BY :passwd USING :dbn;

if(sqlca.sqlcode !=0){
    printf("login failed\n");
}
printf("login success\n");
```

then commond `proc test.pc`, unfortunately there are many errors appeared:

```
Pro*C/C++: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Aug 12 17:58:05 2019
Version 18.1.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /usr/local/lib/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 95, column 1, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:
Error at line 95, column 1 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Pl
atforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrd
er.h
uint16_t
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "uint16_t" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "uint16_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 104, column 1, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:
Error at line 104, column 1 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOr
der.h
uint32_t
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "uint32_t" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "uint32_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 113, column 1, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h:
Error at line 113, column 1 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOr
der.h
uint64_t
1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "uint64_t" when expecting one of the followi
ng:

   ; , = ( [
The symbol ";" was substituted for "uint64_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 52030, column 62, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h:
Error at line 52030, column 62 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develope
r/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityIn
ternal.h
    #define __API_AVAILABLE_GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,NAME,...) NAME
.............................................................1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "..." when expecting one of the following:

   an identifier, define, elif, else, endif, error, if, ifdef,
   ifndef, include, include_next, line, pragma, undef, exec,
   sql, begin, end, var, type, oracle,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token, create,
   function, package, procedure, trigger, or, replace,

Syntax error at line 97, column 9, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:
Error at line 97, column 9 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Pl
atforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h
typedef quad_t *                qaddr_t;
........1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "quad_t" when expecting one of the following
:

   auto, char, const, double, enum, float, int, long,
   ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
   OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
   OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
   short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
   union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile,
   a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "quad_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 33, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_iovec_t.h:
Error at line 33, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Pl
atforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_iovec_
t.h
        size_t   iov_len;       /* [XSI] Size of region iov_base points to */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 303, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 303, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        socklen_t               sae_srcaddrlen; /* size of source address */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "socklen_t" when expecting one of the follow
ing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "socklen_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 305, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 305, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        socklen_t               sae_dstaddrlen; /* size of destination address *
/
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "socklen_t" when expecting one of the follow
ing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "socklen_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 406, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 406, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        sa_family_t     sa_family;      /* [XSI] address family */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "sa_family_t" when expecting one of the foll
owing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "sa_family_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 439, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 439, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        sa_family_t     ss_family;      /* [XSI] address family */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "sa_family_t" when expecting one of the foll
owing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "sa_family_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 543, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 543, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        socklen_t       msg_namelen;    /* [XSI] size of address */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "socklen_t" when expecting one of the follow
ing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "socklen_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 547, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 547, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        socklen_t       msg_controllen; /* [XSI] ancillary data buffer len */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "socklen_t" when expecting one of the follow
ing:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "socklen_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 583, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 583, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        socklen_t       cmsg_len;       /* [XSI] data byte count, including hdr
*/
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "socklen_t" when expecting one of the follow
ing:

   char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "socklen_t" to continue.

Syntax error at line 606, column 2, file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:
Error at line 606, column 2 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/P
latforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h
        pid_t   cmcred_pid;             /* PID of sending process */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "pid_t" when expecting one of the following:

   char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,

Syntax error at line 0, column 0, file lg.pc:
Error at line 0, column 0 in file lg.pc
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "<eof>" when expecting one of the following:

   ; : an identifier, end-exec, random_terminal

Error at line 0, column 0 in file lg.pc
PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing
```

the OS is Mojave and Oracle Client version as above,I guess the errors  are link lib or something about header files, but I dont have any idea to resolve this after what I have done. Anyone who can help is so grateful.

ps.Finally,I give up to solve this problem rational. Just for the intention, I almost solve it by 3 steps
**1**:Find a good environment(docker is a good option or another computer) which can precompiled pro*c file without problem.
**2**:Copy all of files in the path from the `pcscfg.cfg` include a bunch of .h files to your computer.
**3**:Easily change your local  `pcscfg.cfg` file point to the path of the .h files which you copied, and now you can smoothly run the `proc` commond.

Comment: Fix the bugs one-by-one. For a start add `#include <stdint.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem with Mac. On Linux (Oracle Linux 7.6 with gcc 4.8.5) all OK. As a workaround I comment  then precompile by 'oracle proc' and uncomment stdio.h in the precompiled file. After that compile it.

Comment: Finally,I give up to solve this problem rational. Just for the intention, I almost solve it by 3 steps
**1**:Find a good environment(docker is a good option or another computer) which can precompiled pro*c file without problem.
**2**:Copy all of files in the path from the `pcscfg.cfg` include a bunch of .h files to your computer.
**3**:Easily change your local  `pcscfg.cfg` file point to the path of the .h files which you copied, and now you can smoothly run the `proc` commond.

Comment: It seems that Pro*C doesn't work with Apple llvm+clang properly... So I have installed gcc (Homebrew GCC 9.1.0) from homebrew on my Mac and compile with it C-files that I get after Oracle Pro*C precompiler done its work on my virtual Linux (OraLinux 7.6) machine. It's not convenient but it's work path for me if I want to have    executable program on Mac.

Comment: its also a good way to finish this weird problem, I agree that Apple LLVM+clang should take responsibility on this about some little but fatal different about system .h files

Answer (score 0):

pcscfg.cfg file try to add one line:
parse=none